# Defining controller in namespace still Class App\Http\Controllers error taking place in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, laravel-5.5, psr-4

I am working in laravel 5.5. I have created a controller folder with name `Abc` and inside it created a controller file with name `abc.php`, inside this file I have written code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Abc;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class abcController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function NewPromotion()
    {
        return view('new-promotion');
    }
}
```

And in Route folder under web.php file I am calling its view file, like:-
Route::get('/new-promotion','Abc\abcController@NewPromotion');

In spite of defining in namespace I am still getting error i.e.

> "ReflectionException (-1)
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\Abc\abcController does not exist".

What could be the possible issue?

[image: error message appearing in front end]

Comment: Please format all your code as such, by adding 4 spaces infront of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your file is located in `app/Http/Controllers/Abc` directory and has name `abcController.php` (case sensitive).

Also by convention class names start with big letter, so you should rather name your controller `AbcController` and have this file with name `AbcController.php` (and also update your route file to use valid case of this controller name).

Answer (score 0):

Good way to create controller is use cmd (you have to be in project directory)

```
php artisan make:controller "Abc\abcController"
```